# what is the need to transfer an object via network using serialization

Tags: java, serialization

I am going through serialization topic and read that through Serialization we can transfer an object via network . What is the need for Trasfering an object state via Nework and give me a Scenario where this transfer is Useful

Comment: Sometimes it is worth working out the answer for yourself.  How would you suggest passing data from one program to another?

Comment: When you want it to arrive at the other end. What is the need for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`give me a Scenario where this transfer is Useful`

I had the same problem as you some time ago. I understood **how** to serialize an object but didnt understand **why**.

*Imagine real world example such as fast food restaurant's drive through.
You tell in the microphone your order and employee put it in the application. Now guy in the kitchen wants to see order on his monitor and make you a cheesburger and large cola. He is running other instance of application on different JVM so "microphone app" serialize the order and sends it to "kitchen app"*

There are other ways to do it i.e. send basic `txt` file through network but. In this case both programs would need to know a format of the saved file (data types, order of the attributes and delimiters).So serialization greatly simplifies this process

Answer (score 0):

```
How else would you transfer?
```

Finally it will be bytes that will be transferred on the network. How will other end know how to create the original object from these bytes? Serialization is the answer.It can be of many types. You can use Java inbuilt serialization, XML etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. May serialize object to JSON (for example, by Gson lib) and put resulting string by POST or GET (if encode JSON in Base64) to server.
2. If you need send serialized object to some other app (maybe not a server), you may get object bytes and send them via OutputStream (for example, sockets).

Answer (score 0):

For example a clustered environment with high avaliability.

In this scenario (very simplistic) the session associated to every user needs to be serialized to be transfered to the other nodes composing the cluster so if a node breaks down, another node can continue serving the user with no service cut.